# Inline div with static width

Tags: html, css

How can I put div inline and set constant width to it?

My example, which doesn't work proper: http://jsfiddle.net/fl00r/AtJFT/

Comment: A little more detail, please? I don't even know what your problem is.

Comment: If you'll look into example: my div width is 0 while I set it to 100px

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AtJFT/6/

2 changes:

1. Use `display: inline-block`
2. Your second div was blocking the
   first div from displaying on the
   same line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

if you need fixed width you will have you keep it block element, this is the idea ... all the inline elements expands depending on the content