# I have rows of div containers that wrap to each line and the first boxes after the first row indent instead of align left. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, alignment, containers

I have rows of div containers that wrap to each line and the first boxes after the first row indent instead of align left. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="span4" id="_#= $htmlEncode(itemId) =#_" name="Item" style="float:left; margin-bottom:10px; width:150px !important;">
    <div class="pull-left resultBoxContainer" style="height:200px; width:150px !important;">
        <div class="row-fluid" style="margin-top: -5px; padding-top: 0; width:150px !important;">
            <div class="row-fluid" style="width:150px !important;">
                <div class="span4" style="width:50px !important;">
                    <!--#_ if (ctx.CurrentItem.ContentType==' ojpTopic' || ctx.CurrentItem.ContentType==' ojpData') { _#--> <a href="_#=$htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.Path)=#_">
                                <img class="pull-left relatedItemsIconImage" src="_#= iconUrl =#_?Width=50&Height=50" style="width:50px !important; height:50px !important;" alt="" />
                            </a>

                    <!--#_ } else { _#-->
                    <div style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">&nbsp;</div>
                    <!--#_ } _#-->
                </div>
                <div class="span8" style="width:100px !important;"> <a href="_#=$htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.Path)=#_">_#=$htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.Title)=#_</a> 
                    <br />
                    <div class="span5">_#= contentType =#_</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid" style="width:150px !important;">
                <div class="span12" style="width:150px !important;">_#= ojpDescription =#_</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you will want to use `style="display:inline-block;"`. This will respect your `width` settings.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/NJAup/) is a jsfiddle of it in action.

Related question: [Inline div with static width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433783/inline-div-with-static-width)